# Install code from Github with setup.py file

Tags: python, installation, command-line, setup.py

I am trying to use the OpenDutchWordnet from https://github.com/stephantul/OpenDutchWordnet.

I have cloned the directory to my machine and think that I should now execute the setup.py file.

In the Anaconda Prompt (from the directory in which setup.py is located) I ran both:

`python setup.py`

and

`python3 setup.py`

However, both return:

[image]

What do I need to do set up the code properly?

Comment: Append `install` to what you entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Packages With **setup.py**

```
$ python setup.py install
```

**or**

```
$ setup.py install
```

> You can find more information about installing packages in Python
> resources

References:

- [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/install/)